# C++ Calculate string mod string

Tags: c++, string, int, modulo

I have a 2 very large numbers that are too large to be use in unsigned long so I put them in strings.

I want to make an operation of mod between these strings and to get a string that represent the result.

```
#include <string>

void main()
{
    string num1 = "123...";
    string num2 = "123...";

    string result = modStrings(num1, num2);
}
```

Is anything like that possible?
Thanks.

Comment: That is not possible with what is provided in C++ and its standard library.  You'd have to write your own, or consider using one of the third party "big number" libraries.  I'm partial to [calc](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/) by Landon "Chongo" Curt Noll.